# My LTO tape drive is slow and “shoe-shines” on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, scsi, tape

Regardless of what data I write to my LTO-4 tape drive `/dev/nsa0`, writing is very slow (less than 1 MB/s) and the tape is constantly being wound back and forth in a shoe-shine pattern. No speed problem occurs when reading or erasing (with `mt erase`) tapes.

It appears that this problem occurs since I tried to enable SMART monitoring on the tape drive using `smartctl`.

Comment: What block size are you using when writing?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick 1 MB using a kernel with patched `MAXPHYS`. The effect is independent of block size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible that the buffering mode has been set to “unbuffered.” This is a special feature of LTO tape drives, forcing them to return from a WRITE command only after the data has been written to the tape. This stops any streaming from happening and causes the observed effects.

Unfortunately FreeBSD does not provide the `mt drvbuffer 1` command from Linux to turn buffering back on, but it is possible to manually send an appropriately crafted MODE SELECT command to the drive to turn buffering back on:

```
camcontrol cmd /dev/nsa0 -c '15 10 00 00 04 00' -o 4 '0 0 10 0'
```

If you have more than one tape drive, replace `/dev/nsa0` with an appropriate device file.